# DBeaver. Network is unreachable

Tags: sql-server, dbeaver, jtds

When trying connect to server with old SQL Server jTDS driver I encountered with Network error IOException: Network is unreachable Network is unreachable
[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn2go.png)

I was reinstall dbeaver and reinstall drivers for this connection, all works on another PCs on Ubuntu and Windows, but doesn't work on macOS

Comment: How "old" is this server? What version of SQL Server is it?

Comment: 2005 if memory serves me

Comment: If you open Terminal on macOS and `traceroute yourServerNameOrIpAddress` does it resolve to an IP address and route at least part of the way across the network? The error suggests to me that the IP of the server is in a private network address block that your Mac doesn't know about. i.e.: do you need a VPN connection established to connect to it?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning all ok, mac resolve to server, dbeaver connection was working at week ago, at first i thought it was an update or due to server relocation but it's strange that it works everywhere except my pc

Comment: @AlwaysLearning my applications on node works too with this server and db's both on the web and locally